# Compute similarity between document and specific keywords

Tags: python, nlp, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I have a collection of newspaper (unlabeled, just raw articles) articles on a disease. I also have three set of manually chosen keywords associated with the disease eg: `phase-1`,`phase-2` etc like below.

```
phase_1 = ["symptoms","signs","fever","ache","vomit","blood","headache","fatigue","breath"]

phase_2 = ["pathogen","flavivirus","swamp","virus","contagious","mosquito bite","virus","agent","host"]
```

Is there anyways to calculate the similarities between a set of keywords and the news articles, using PYTHON ?

Comment: From a Google search on "cosine similarity python", the top result is [sklearns cosine_similarity() function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html). Perhaps that is a good starting point to explore?

Comment: yeah i am trying to modify it to my needs now.

Answer (score 1):

You can define various similiarity metrics for such a task. You can then go to see which one works best. Here are some ideas:

1.) As pointed out in the post by Max, you can calculate the Jaccard index between the document and each of the two lists. The Jaccard index is defined as the intersection divided by the union of the two items:

```
set1 = set(news_article.split())
set2 = set(phase_1)

jcc = len(set1.intersection(set2)) / len(set1.union(set2))
```

The higher the jaccard index, the more similar the text is with the list. However, the Jaccard index would only work if your news articles contain exactly the words that you have defined in your lists. A text that contains words that are semantically similar, but different to the ones in your list would still have a jaccard index of 0, even though it has similar words in it.

2.) I recommend to also try out a slightly more advanced approach based on the Word Mover's Distance (WMD). For this you would need a representation of your words in some vector space (e.g. obtained by a word2vec model). Then, you can represent a news article and one of your lists as a collection of vectors in that space. The metric measures how different the two representations are (how much do you have to move one representation to match the other). The smaller the distance the more similar the two representations.

You can probably train your word2vec model on your news article. I'd suggest to use gensim for training the model and to later evaluate the word mover's distance.

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_wmd.html

It's not guaranteed to work, but I'd give it a shot. In my experience the WMD usually works better than cosine distance, but it of course depends on the application.

Both approaches would also depend on the text processing that you do beforehand. Make sure that your news article will be in the format that you expect before evaluating the metrics/training the word2vec model.

Comment: thanks for the first idea! I kinda had missed Max's point in his answer there. Eitherways, it works decently. 
In case of the second one, I actually tried doing that at first...but the result wasn't very satisfactory. And also my data is unlabeled and there aren't any good pre-trained model for Bengali :(

Answer (score 0):

When naming your lists, I don't recommend using dashes or other top characters. I hope this helps:

```
phase_1 =  ["symptoms","signs","fever","ache","vomit","blood","headache","fatigue","breath"]

phase_2 = ["pathogen","flavivirus","swamp","virus","contagious","mosquito bite","virus","agent","host"]

# Performing the calculations
res = len(set(phase_1) & set(phase_2))
res2 = res / float(len(set(phase_1) | set(phase_2))) * 100

# Showing the results
msg = "The percentage of smilarity between the 2 lists is:"
print(msg, res2)
```

Comment: oh, i just used that naming in a haste while writing here. I will fix it.

Comment: eitherways, I don't need the similarity between these lists. I need to calculate similarity of news articles with these lists. like:
-> article-1 has 55% similarities to phase_1

Comment: Then you have to provide some sort of API to open this article. Unless you can manually add the names of articles to a new list.